# Nested if statements for distributing data in R

Tags: r, if-statement, distribution

I have census data with 4 columns (Age, Broad Age, Gender, Ethnicity) and multiple rows for each individual. Separate to this I have data on employment type for different age groups and ethnicities. From the datasets I know the number of people in each employment type by "Age" group but only know ethnicity of the people by "Broad Age" group.

For example, I know 23 males aged 16-19, 53 males aged 20-21, and 42 males aged 22-24 work in part time employment, but I only know ethnicity for the "Broad Age" group of 16-24, which I know 38 males are white, and so on.

I am new to R and have managed to do IF statements for if "gender" & if "Age" then they are in Part Time employment but that populates all rows. I am trying to find a way I can specify the distributions according to what I know from the census data so the fifth column populates the correct number of part time employees by "Age" group, but for the "Broad Age" randomly allocates in each ethnic group.

I think I need to create a function but am a little confused with incorporating the distribution part. Any advice would greatly be received!

Example data:

```
Age     Broad Age       Gender      Ethnicity
16-17   16-24       Male            White
16-17   16-24       Male            White
16-17   16-24       Male            Asian
16-17   16-24       Male            Asian
16-17   16-24       Male            Asian
18-19   16-24       Male            White
18-19   16-24       Male            White
18-19   16-24       Male            White
18-19   16-24       Male            White
18-19   16-24       Male            White
```

Example external data (Employment by age):

```
Age      Part-time  Full-time   S-E: Part-time  S-E: Full-time  Unemployed   Student

16 to 19    23.20%   5.52%         0.00%            0.55%         11.60%      58.56%
20 to 21    11.33%   1.97%         1.48%            0.00%         6.40%       78.82%
22 to 24    13.30%   18.09%        1.06%            2.13%         9.57%       54.26%
```

Example external data (employment type by ethnicity and Broad Age):
For Males 16-24:

```
Employment Type    White    Mixed/Multiple    Asian    African   Caribbean    Other
Part-time          93.27%      0.90%           4.48%     0%        0.45%        0.90%
Full-time          94.64%      0.89%           5.0%      0%         0.86%       1.79%
```

What I need based on the percentages from external data:

```
Age     Broad Age       Gender      Ethnicity    Employment Type
16-17   16-24       Male            White          Student
16-17   16-24       Male            White          Part-time
16-17   16-24       Male            Asian          Student
16-17   16-24       Male            Asian          Student
16-17   16-24       Male            Asian          Full-time
18-19   16-24       Male            White          Student
18-19   16-24       Male            White          Student
18-19   16-24       Male            White          Unemployed
18-19   16-24       Male            White          S-E:full-time
18-19   16-24       Male            White          Student
```

Is there a way to fill the 5th column (employment type) based on the distribution I know from the two external sources?

Comment: From your example data, it should be possible to get the numbers of different `Ethnicity`ies by `Age`. Does your example data not match your situation? I gather you have 2 distinct datasets. Can you provide example data for both sets, & an example output to show what you want to achieve?

Comment: The example data does match the situation, the external datasets are where the problem lies. I think what I need to do is something along the lines of if 16-17 & male then x% work in PT employment, then, if between 16-24 & male, x% of PT employees are white (for example).

I will add additional data below as can't fit it in here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would include a new column that groups the Age class into the Broad Age class as for some analysis you need to reduce the age resolution anyhow as you cannot increase it for the Broad Age group. So Age '16-17', '18-19', '19-20', '21-22', '22-23' would get in the new column the tag '16-24' comparable to the Broad Age group. Then you can use merge to combine them e.g.

```
merge(dataset1,dataset2,by=c("new_age_group"),all.x=TRUE,incomparables=NA)
```

to create the new column beforehand use something like

```
dataset1$new_age_group[dataset1$Age == '19-20'] <- '16-24'
```

Comment: Thanks @horseshoe, I will create a new merged column which may make distributing the data a bit easier for these age categories. I have more data that groups the "age" in 5 year groups, but then the ethnicity increases to 25 year "broad age" groups. Hopefully I will figure it incorporating the distributions soon!